# Python 2D dictionary

Tags: python

https://github.com/ewmiller/syn-detector/blob/master/detector.py

I was making a syn packet detector referring to this and I've been trying to add who_got_scanned() function using 2D dictionary.

I wanted outputs like this but somehow it wouldn't work.

```
[+] Found : 128.3.23.5                                                                                               
[+] count (SYN) : 34                                      
[+] count (SYN_ACK) : 1                                   
    [+] Scanned IP address : 196.119.124.204              
    [+] Scanned IP address : 196.119.124.132              
    [+] Scanned IP address : 196.119.124.231
```

I am new to python so I made a simple program to demonstrate my understanding.

```
test.py

x = {
        '1.1.1.1' : {
            '1.1.1.1' : 1,
            '2.2.2.2' : 2,
            '3.3.3.3' : 3,
            '4.4.4.4' : 4
            }
        }

for k in x.keys() :
    if k == '1.1.1.1' :
        for k2 in x[k].keys() :
            print(str(k2))

The result

1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

First '1.1.1.1' ip address is a source ip address. And the inline keys and values are destination ip addresses and SYN packets they received respectively.

So I intended to print key values only, which is destionation ip addresses, and it worked well.

So I adopted this to my SYN scanner code. But it keeps occurring an error and I don't know what is wrong.

```
def who_got_scanned(src_addr, dst_addr) :
    if src_addr in scanned_addr :
        if dst_addr in scanned_addr[src_addr] :
            scanned_addr[src_addr][dst_addr] = scanned_addr[src_addr][dst_addr] + 1
        else :
            scanned_addr[src_addr][dst_addr] = 1

    else :
        scanned_addr[src_addr] = dst_addr
```

This is who_got_scanned() function.

And this is my code to print out scanned ip addresses.

```
for k1, v1 in addresses.items() : 
    if v1[0] >= v1[1] * 3 : 
        print("[+] Found : " + k1) 
        print("[+] count (SYN) : " + str(v1[0])) 
        print("[+] count (SYN_ACK) : " + str(v1[1])) 
        for k2 in scanned_addr.keys() : 
            if k1 == k2 : 
                for k3 in scanned_addr[k2].keys() : 
                    print("\t[+] Scanned IP address : " + str(k3)) 
        print("==============================================")
```

I don't see any difference between my scanner and test.py.

Why is my code not working?

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: syntax error in: `str(scanned_addr[k2][v]2)`

Comment: @ddcastrodd
File "detector.py", line 58, in printPcap
    for k3 in scanned_addr[k2].keys() :
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: It looks like you are going too many levels down. There is nothing at scanned_addr[k2] and therefore no keys as well.